# Getting null value while displaying contacts in iphone phonegap application

Tags: iphone, html, ios5, cordova, contacts

I am working on Phonegap application and trying to get the contacts of the device.

What I have done from [this reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) is as follows :

```
function onDeviceReady() {       
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName"];

    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
 }

// contacts Methods
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].addresses.length; j++) {
            alert("Pref: " + contacts[i].addresses[j].pref + "\n" +
                  "Type: " + contacts[i].addresses[j].type + "\n" +
                  "Formatted: " + contacts[i].addresses[j].formatted + "\n" + 
                  "Street Address: "  + contacts[i].addresses[j].streetAddress + "\n" + 
                  "Locality: "  + contacts[i].addresses[j].locality + "\n" + 
                  "Region: "  + contacts[i].addresses[j].region + "\n" + 
                  "Postal Code: "  + contacts[i].addresses[j].postalCode + "\n" +                          
                  "Country: "  + contacts[i].addresses[j].country);
            }
        }
    };

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    function onError(contactError){
        alert('onError!');
    }
```

In console while printing the contacts I am getting this error-

```
  [INFO] Error in success callback: Contacts1 = TypeError: 'null' is not an object
```

There are contacts in my simulator and contact information is not null still I am getting null. Not sure about the reason.

Please help me.

EDIT : same thing is happening when I am playing audio files ..

Any one have idea why this is happening ??